# Insert text between 2 delimeters

Tags: c#, regex, delimiter

I have a string that looks something like this

`Say_Hi~~~Say_Opt1~~Say_Opt3~~~Say_Opt6~~~Say_Opt9~~Say_GoodBye`

It has 16 '~' dividing it into 17 "sections". In section number 5, I need to insert `Say_Opt5`.

`Say_Hi~~~Say_Opt1~~Say_Opt3~~Say_Opt5~Say_Opt6~~~Say_Opt9~~Say_GoodBye`

So I need to be able to take a string, and a position, and isert the string into the position specified. I tried using a regex but im not entire sure how matches work.

```
 string baseString = "Say_Hi~~~Say_Opt1~~Say_Opt3~~~Say_Opt6~~~Say_Opt9~~Say_GoodBye";

var newString = new Regex("~").Replace(baseString, "Say_Opt5", 7);
```

Also, there may already be an Option 5, so I need to replace the old option5 with the new option 5. Such as replacing

`Say_Hi~~~Say_Opt1~~Say_Opt3~~Say_Opt5~Say_Opt6~~~Say_Opt9~~Say_GoodBye`

with

`Say_Hi~~~Say_Opt1~~Say_Opt3~~Say_Opt5_Custom~Say_Opt6~~~Say_Opt9~~Say_GoodBye`

Comment: Show what you tried - and the world will try to fix it!

Comment: How comes that position 7 (0-based) is section number 5?

Comment: Thats the location where opt5 goes, if there is an option5. As for why, the answer is always legacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var s1 = "there~is~a~~cat";
var s2 = "super";
var words = s1.Split('~').ToList();
//words.Insert(3, s2); // this will insert new token
words[3] = s2; // this will replace word at specific index
var res = string.Join("~", words.ToArray());
```

After this your cat will become a super hero, it will become a super cat :)

Comment: sorry, i forgot the last part, can this handle that?

Comment: ..dur me. Ty, long day.

Comment: No need to call `.ToArray()`. `String.Join` accepts `IEnumerable` as second argument, `List` would work just fine there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C#, you can use this:

```
string s = "Say_Hi~~~Say_Opt1~~Say_Opt3~~~Say_Opt6~~~Say_Opt9~~Say_GoodBye";
MessageBox.Show(s);
string[] parts = s.Split('~');
parts[YourIntegerIndex] = "YouNewString";
s = string.Join("~", parts);
MessageBox.Show(s);
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot the last part, can this handle that?